# Center images within bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to create responsive carousel in bootstrap but images with lower width than carousel's are moving to the left.

Here is the code:

```css
.tales {
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner{
  width:100%;
  
  max-height: 400x !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- inner -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600/2c3e50/000" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x1200/d35400/000" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600/c0392b/000" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    
  </div>

</div>
```

It is better to look at when snippet gets expanded.
It is taking way longer than it should..

Comment: Do you want the images to be centered inside the carousel?

Comment: Yes, but it is only needed when width of the image is lower than carousel's

Answer (score 6, accepted):

set `display:inline-block`in **img** and set `text-align:center` in **.item**

**check snippet below-**

```css
.tales {
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner{
  width:100%;
  
  max-height: 400x !important;
}
.item{
text-align:center;
}
.carousel-inner img{
display:inline-block  !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- inner -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600/2c3e50/000" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x1200/d35400/000" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600/c0392b/000" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can given margin: 0 auto; for img tag.

```
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img, .carousel-inner>.item>img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: You did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.carousel-inner>.item.active, .carousel-inner>.item.next.left, .carousel-inner>.item.prev.right {
    text-align: -webkit-center;

}
```

**UPDATED SNIPPET**

```css
.tales {
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner{
  width:100%;
  
  max-height: 400x !important;
}
.carousel-inner>.item.active, .carousel-inner>.item.next.left, .carousel-inner>.item.prev.right {
    text-align: -webkit-center;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- inner -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600/2c3e50/000" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x1200/d35400/000" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600/c0392b/000" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Antoher way to center them is by using flexbox. You basically have to add these two properties `display: flex; justify-content: center;` to your .carousel-inner class. `display: flex;` will create a flexbox and `justify-content: center;`will center the images horizontally.

```css
.tales {
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner{
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; 
  max-height: 400x !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- inner -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img  src="http://placehold.it/1200x600/2c3e50/000" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x1200/d35400/000" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600/c0392b/000" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

i think this may help for you. i tried your code it is working fine for me

for a bootstrap carousel or any sliders it is better to pick up all images with same height and width

else, we need to fix the weight and width to some height using css

```
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .carousel-inner img
   {
     width: 100%;
     height: 500px !important;
   }
</style>
<!-- html-->
<div class="container">
 <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- inner -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600/2c3e50/000" class="img-responsive" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x1200/d35400/000" class="img-responsive" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600/c0392b/000" class="img-responsive" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

 </div>
</div>
```